# python: read data from stdin and raw_input

Tags: python, stdin, eoferror

I want to pass some data to a python script using echo and after that promote the user to input options. I am running through an `EOFError` which I think is happening since I read all data in `sys.stdin`. How do I fix this issue? Thanks!

code.py:

```
x = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
  x += line
y = raw_input()
```

usage:

```
echo -e -n '1324' | ./code.py
```

error at `raw_input()`:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just cannot send data through stdin (that's redirecting) and then get back the interactive mode.

When you perform `a | b`, b cannot read from standard input anymore. If it wants to do that, it will stop as soon as `a` finishes and breaks the pipe.

But when `a` finishes, it does not mean than you get hold of `stdin` again.

Maybe you could change the way you want to do things, example:

```
echo -n -e '1324' | ./code.py
```

becomes

```
./code.py '1234' '5678'
```

and use `sys.argv[]` to get the value of `1234`, `5678`...

```
import sys

x = ''
for line in sys.argv[1:]:
  x += line+"\n"

y = raw_input()
```

if you have a lot of lines to output, pass an argument which is a file and what you'll read

```
import sys

x = ''
for line in open(sys.argv[1],"r"):
  x += line

y = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
{ echo -e -n '1324'; cat; } | ./code.py
```

First `echo` will write the literal string to the pipe, then `cat` will read from standard input and copy that to the pipe. The python script will see this all as its standard input.

Comment: Did you type something? You need to type stuff and then type Ctl-d to signal EOF.

Comment: I think I now understand what you meant. Thanks